# My application doesn't work with OnTouchListener

Tags: android-studio

I do not know why my program stops when I run it. The application does not display anything, I only get the error: "The application closed", but nothing was displayed on the screen, neither the background nor the buttons in the application appeared.

I noticed that this happens when I attach a picture to the button

public class Telecomanda extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public Button btnFata, btnFataDreapta, btnFataStanga, btnSpate, btnFar, btnGaraj, btnObstacol;

public BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
public BluetoothDevice device;
public BluetoothSocket socket;
public OutputStream outputStream;

String ip = "192.168.1.102";

String comand;

public final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString( "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" ); //SPP UUID
public final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:18:E4:35:08:B6"; // HC-05 BT ADDRESS


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_telecomanda );
    this.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( 1024 );

    //  declarare butoane
    btnFata = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnFata );
    btnSpate = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnSpate );
    btnFataDreapta = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnFataDreapta );
    btnFataStanga = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnFataStanga );
    btnGaraj = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnGaraj );

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice( DEVICE_ADDRESS );

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    } else {
        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
            startActivityForResult( enableIntent, 3 );
        } else {
            ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread( device );
            connectThread.start();
        }
    }


    btnFata.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                comand = "1";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                comand = "5";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );


    btnFataDreapta.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                comand = "3";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                comand = "5";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );


    btnFataStanga.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                comand = "4";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                comand = "5";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );


    btnSpate.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                comand = "2";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                comand = "5";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );


    btnObstacol.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (socket != null) {
                comand = "6";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                comand = "5";
                try {
                    outputStream.write( comand.getBytes() );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } );



    btnGaraj.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            commandArduino( "http://" + ip + "/?cmd=1" );
        }
    } );
}

public void commandArduino(String url) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.execute( new HttpGet( url ) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/images"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context="com.td.daniela.control_masina.Telecomanda">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFata"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fata"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.096" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpate"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFataDreapta"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/stanga"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.306"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFataStanga"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/dreapta"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.693"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGaraj"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Check in logcat for the errors. There's most probably some exception related to the image. May be it's not in resource folder

Comment: _"I do not know why my program stops when I run it."_ This helps: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).